# Ports 80 and 443 Closed

Tags: amazon-web-services, port, jupyterhub

I'm currently attempting to setup a jupyterhub instance on AWS using a Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

I have been using this tutorial https://gist.github.com/widdowquinn/e91b9bb850ece8873bbd084944798fe2 and for some reason when trying to access jupyter.uiuc-bdeep.org using a browser the connection is always refused/unable to connect. Further snooping has revealed using TCP scanning sites that ports 80 and 443 are closed.

I'm not sure what is going on due to my EC2 security group inbound rules being open to all connections on port 80 and 443. Please let me know what is possible to solve this issue.

[Snapshot of current security group configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk6xf.png)

Comment: Is your VPC open on those ports? Check your VPC network ACLs

Comment: How would one check what ports are open on my VPC? I'm in the sidebar of VPC and cannot seem to find anything related to ports.

Comment: Just because your security group allows the port does not mean anything is listening.  Is your process running on the machine?  Is it listening on the correct interface (likely `0.0.0.0` unless there is a proxy in front)?

Comment: Yeah jupyterhub is running on the machine. I'm not sure how to get it to listen on the correct interface though, I used wget on 0.0.0.0 as well as jupyter.uiuc-bdeep.org but it fails to connect citing 0.0.0.0:80 and 34.235.87.80:80 respectively.

Comment: If you do a `netstat -na | grep 80 | grep LISTEN`, what do you get?  My guess is that it's `127.0.0.1`, not `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @AlexMoore VPC -> Network ACLs